# Кастомный View в SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

У меня в проекте множество схожих.одинаковых элементов, по этому есть желание это как-то унифицировать, сделал это так:

```
struct BorderedTextField: View {
    @State var text: String
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold, design: .default))
            .autocapitalization(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.none/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("White_10"), lineWidth: 1))
    }
}

struct BorderedTextFieldWithTitle: View {
    let title: String
    @State var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title).foregroundColor(Color("Gray")).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            Spacer().frame(height: 5)
            BorderedTextField(text: text)
        }
    }
}
```

использую так:

```
struct LoginScreen: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var model = LoginViewModel()
    
    @State var email = ""
    
    @State var pass = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Color("WindowBackground")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .overlay(
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Image("homfy_logo")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Spacer().frame(height: 10)
                        BorderedTextFieldWithTitle(title: "Email", text: email)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 10)
                        PasswordTextFieldWithTitle(title: "Password", text: pass)
                        Spacer().frame(height: 15)
                        BlueButton(action: {
                            self.model.loginUser(email: email, pass: pass)
                        })
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 18, leading: 20, bottom: 18, trailing: 20))
            )
    }
}
```

В целом работает не плохо, но одна проблема, емайл и пароль (биндинги) остаются пустыми. Если же выношу из структур, то получаю нормально работающий вариант.

P.S. Я понимаю что я что-то делаю не правильно, но не могу понять что, у меня совсем мало опыта в iOS и Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я дополню ответ т.к. не совсем коректно написан второй ответ

```
struct BorderedTextField: View {
    @Binding var text: String // Модификатор
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold, design: .default))
            .autocapitalization(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.none/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("White_10"), lineWidth: 1))
    }
}

struct BorderedTextFieldWithTitle: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var text: String // Модификатор
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title).foregroundColor(Color("Gray")).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            Spacer().frame(height: 5)
            BorderedTextField(text: text)
        }
    }
}
```

если же нужно использовать кастомный инициализатор то это выглядит следующим образом

```
struct BorderedTextField: View {
    @Binding var text: String  // Модификатор

    init(_ text: Binding<String>) {
       _text = text // вот здесь нижнее подчеркивание. Это присвоение биндинга.
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $text)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold, design: .default))
            .autocapitalization(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.none/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("White_10"), lineWidth: 1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, нужно `@State var text: String` поменять на `let text: Binding<String>`, а на самом верху оставить как было.